# Tab Bar Item disappears after adding Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7

First I created a VC with `TabBarController` like this.
The other tabs and the main controller are at other storyboards.

[image]

Then, I added the `Navigation Controller` from the Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.

And the `TabBarItem` immediately disappears.

[image]

How can I change my tab bar icons and names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard you can change the tab icon from the Navigation controller. (Provided you have different navigation controllers for different tabs of your tab bar controller). YOUR NC will look something like this. (NC -> VC)

[image: Check this Image]

Comment: It doesn't show up here, this is what it look like  <http://i.imgur.com/URlXRlo.png> , and before this there was the bigger tab controller which I can not edit as well <http://i.imgur.com/LqNXJRy.png>

Comment: It is because you are using Storyboard Referrence with Relationship Segues, which is not supported in ios 8.0
Try removing those storyboard referrence and include all your tab bar relationship segues in same storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I checked your attach images. There are no issue with your navigation controller it will work fine with your tab bar.